# GoYAML - Convert string input to type on Unmarshal

Tags: go

I have a struct defined for my Yaml file like so:

```
type Service struct {
    ServiceName  string       `yaml:"service_name"`
    PipelineType PipelineType `yaml:"pipeline_type"`
}
```

In the file, this struct comes in as a string:

```
    service_name: service
    pipeline_type: app
```

My type is defined like this:

```
// PipelineType Pipeline Types
type PipelineType struct {
    Value string
}

var (
    AppPipeline           = PipelineType{"app"}
    ...
)
```

Because of the type declaration, I'm getting the following error (expected):

```
line 4: cannot unmarshal !!str `app` into main.PipelineType
```

Is there a way to tell GoYAML, or create some form of consturctor to convert the value using `string(PipelineType)` or something similar?

Alternatively, is there a "GoYAML" friendly way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
type Service struct {
    ServiceName  string       `yaml:"service_name"`
    PipelineType PipelineType `yaml:"pipeline_type"`
}

func (s *Service) myYml() *Service {

    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("service.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    } 
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return s
}
```

get it:

```
var s Service
s.myYml()
```

Comment: Ah sorry, so this would work, if the file only contained these values. The problem is by this stage, I've already Unmarshaled the larger file with these contents. I'm still looking at options, thank you.